# RobotFramework - WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/safaridriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Tags: robotframework, safaridriver

I'm using Robot Framework to execute some tests on the products of the society I'm working in. Actually, my tests are running on a macOS machine. I can remotely launch tests on firefox and chrome and everything works fine. When I'm trying to launch the same test remotely on Safari I get this error :

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/safaridriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

I checked the console and these errors come out when the machine tries to launch the safaridriver :

```
authd         Fatal: interaction not allowed (kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed not set)
safaridriver  Authorization failed with error -60007.
authd         copy_rights: authorization failed
```

What I already tried: I allowed remote automation on the safari browser and launched this as the user executing the tests :

```
sudo safaridriver --enable
```

Moreover, if I connect in Screen Sharing with the macOS machine and reproduce the exact behavior manually, everything is working fine and test is launched on Safari Browser. To launch the tests remotely I use a Tomcat server.

Here are the versions of the tools I use :
Python 2.7.16
Selenium 3.141.0
Robotframework 3.0.2
macOS Mojave 10.14.6
Safari 14.0.1 (14610.2.11.51.10) (safaridriver is bundled with it)

I would like these tests to launch remotely exactly as on firefox or chrome, I've already looked many other questions here but I didn't find any solution.
I'm new with working on macOS so there must be something I'm missing about how to authorize processes on Mac, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem and I'm posting it here so if anyone has the same trouble can try this.

The solution was that my Tomcat Server was launched by a system user that doesn't have display rights so when I restarted the server with a user that have these rights (basic user account) the safaridriver could be launched and it worked fine.

The fact that it was only a problem related to safaridriver is that now safaridriver comes bundled with Safari so I guess Mac add this kind of protection to their own binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. After I upgrade the OS to 14.1.1, it is working now.
upgraded:
OS to 14.1.1
Safari 17.1
Selenium 4.15.2